# Django : Adding a new row in a table based on a foreign key value using serializers via POST method

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am very new to serializers. I have two models currently.

**models.py**

```
class ChatSession(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    staff       = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    started_at  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    closed_at   = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class ChatMessages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name="my_messages")
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    message = models.TextField(null=False)

    message_types = [
        ('image', 'Image'),
        ('video', 'Video'),
        ('text', 'Text'),
        ('audio', 'Audio'),
    ]

    message_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=message_types, null=False, default='text')
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    chat_session = models.ForeignKey(ChatSession,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return ChatMessages.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta: 
        model = ChatMessages
        fields = "__all__"

class ChatSessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ChatSession
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
#For fetching all msgs of a user
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
class Chat(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs['user_id']
        #id = request.user.id
        Chat = ChatMessages.objects.filter(user_id=id)
        serializer = ChatSerializer(Chat, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
class ChatSessionMessages(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs['chat_session_id']
        Messages = ChatMessages.objects.filter(chat_session=id)
        serializer = ChatSerializer(Messages, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs['chat_session_id']


*what should I add here???*
```

When my URL hits chat/<chat_session_id>/  I want to add a message to that particular session. How to I specify the data in request body to have that chat session id column be filled with id from URL and message from request.data?

I have already tried

```
 if 'message' in request.POST:
        message = request.POST['message']
 else:
        message = 'FAIL'
        
        user = request.user

        chat_session = ChatSession.objects.get(id=id)
        
        ChatMessages.objects.create(user_id=user.id, is_staff=False, message=message, message_type='Text',  chat_session=chat_session)
        
        return Response(
            {
            'status': 'SUCCESS',
             'message': message,
             #'user': deserialize_user(user),
             }
            )
```

This always results in FAIL being added to table. Also, I plan on using serializers.

Comment: So what is the structure of the data you send from the frontend? why isn't message present in the data?

Comment: Hi, the .create method worked!The structure is {
    "message":"TEST MESSAGE",
}